# Does $\mathbb{Z} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Z} \star \mathbb{Z} \star \mathbb{Z} \star \mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

Probably very trivial, I'm pretty sure it does. Just want to make sure.

We note that $\mathbb{Z} \star \mathbb{Z}$ is the free group on two letters. In this case, we are consider the free group on 4 letters.

Comment: What exactly is your problem with this?

Comment: Can you give a map? The real cool question is this: can you find an injection back the other way!?

Comment: @User0112358 Not sure if that question is cool, given that its answer is trivial...

Answer (score 4):

Let $\{a,b,c,d\}$ be a basis for $\mathbb Z \star \mathbb Z \star \mathbb Z \star \mathbb Z$ and consider
$$
\iota \colon \mathbb Z \to  \mathbb Z \star \mathbb Z \star \mathbb Z \star \mathbb Z, z \mapsto a^z,
$$
where
$$
a^z := \begin{cases}
\underbrace{aa\ldots a}_{z \text{ times}} & \text{, if } z \ge 0 \\
\underbrace{a^{-1}a^{-1}\ldots a^{-1}}_{-z \text{ times}} & \text{, if } z < 0
\end{cases}
$$

You need to verify that

1. $\iota$ is a group homomorphism and
2. $\iota$ is injective (this follows easily from 1.).

Answer (score 1):

Subgroups of free groups are free, and in particular torsion-free. Thus the map $1 \to g$ is a well-defined injection $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}^{*4}$ for any $g\not = 1$.

Comment: Given how basic OP's question is, I fear that your abuse of notation may lead to confusion. To clarify: anomaly is talking about the function $\tau \colon \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z \star \mathbb Z \star \mathbb Z \star \mathbb Z, z \mapsto g^z$ just like in my post for any $g \in \mathbb Z \star \mathbb Z \star \mathbb Z \star \mathbb Z$ that is not (equivalent to) the empty word.

Comment: @Stefan: What's abusive about the notation?

Comment: You mention the 'map' $1 \to g$, but actually mean the unique group homomorphism $\tau \colon \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z \star \mathbb Z \star \mathbb Z \star \mathbb Z$ such that $\tau(1) = g$. Also, instead of writing $1 \to g$, it is more common to write $1 \mapsto g$. This helps to distinguish it from a map $f$ with domain $1$ and range $g$. Also $g \neq 1$ may be confusion - depending on how OP was introduces to free groups and the way their group structure was presented. Let me be clear: All of this is (mostly) fine, but may be confusing to someone who apparently is new to the subject.

Comment: @Stefan: I think that's veering into pedantry (especially with drawing a distinction between $\to$ and $\mapsto$, which I would say is not common at all), even at the level at the OP's question, but notation is just notation.